# How does this program evaluate?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void showbits(unsigned int x)
{
    int i; 
    for(i=(sizeof(int)*8)-1; i>=0; i--)
        (x&(1<<i))?putchar('1'):putchar('0');

    printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
    int j = 5225, m, n;
    printf("The decimal %d is equal to binary - ", j);
    /* assume we have a function that prints a binary string when given 
       a decimal integer 
     */
    showbits(j); 

    /* the loop for right shift operation */
    for ( m = 0; m <= 5; m++ ) {
        n = j >> m;
        printf("%d right shift %d gives ", j, m);
        showbits(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain it in detail. Like why is it written `1<<i` instead of `i>>1`??? 
How will the condition evaluate for various binary numbers???

Comment: Not the down voter but you need to show more knowledge of the problem if you want a good answer. What do you think this line does? What aspect is not clear? Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows you tried this and explain what aspect of the output you don't understand?

Comment: Okay, seeing this in context I really have to agree that you should have been able to experiment to find the answer yourself. If you had just read this expression in isolation somewhere, I could understand a neophyte being confused about what it does, but this is a working program that you could compile and modify yourself to understand its behavior. -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `x << y` means "`x` shifted to the left by `y` number of bits". `1 << i` will return an integer with bit `i` set to 1 and all other bits set to 0.

(`i >> 1`, on the other hand, means "shift `i` to the right by one bit". They're not comparable operations at all.  Suppose `i` is 5: `1 << i` will return the binary number `00100000`, or 32, whereas `i >> 1` will return the binary number `00000010`, or 2.)

`x & (1 << i)` will perform a bitwise AND operation on `x` and `1 << i`, which amounts to checking whether `x` has bit `i` set to 1. If it does, this will return a positive number; if not, it will return 0.

So the overall result of this expression will be to print the character `1` if `x` has bit `i` set to 1, and print `0` if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The author used the ternary operator ?: instead of if-then-else which would communicate clearer.

`1<<i` is a 1-bit shifted to a higher significance, example i=3:  `0001b` becomes `1000b`.

This shifted set bit is then used to test the bit in `x` at that bit-position.

If that bit in `x` is 1 then the first putchar is evaluated, else the second.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it written `1<<i` instead of `i>>1`???

`1 << i` means: Shift the the bit `1` **left** n-times. So the bit is set at position 0 and then shifted how often it is indicated by the value of `i`. Each successive shift operation constitutes a multiply by 2.

`i>>1` This is quite a different operation, because it shifts the bits **right** and the operators are reversed, so this means `shift the value in i right for one position`. This is essentialy a division by 2.

These bit shift operation scan be used for some specific things. For example, they were used for fast multiplicactions/divisions of int for known numbers, because these operations are faster than doing an FPU operation for register sized values.

Another usage is to keep various bits in a single byte and mask them to test if they are set, or if you want to set them. In older times, this was often used to preserve memory (when memory was small and expensive). It is still needed on hardware devices, because there you often have hardware registers signaling various states in individual bits.

Answer (score 0):

It just outputs the bitpattern of x to the screen, but in inverted order, that means if e.g. x is `char` and `x == 5` then it prints: `10100000` (instead of 00000101). It is done by `1<<i` and not `1>>i` to not have to set `i` to the most significant bit depending on which type `x` has.

But you could write:

```
( x & (1<<(sizeof(x)*8-1-i)) ) ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
```

Then you would have it in the right order.